# More than one answer by the same user

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I hacked together this little [query on the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/172183/more-than-one-answer-by-the-same-user)

The query finds questions where an answerer has posted two or more answers (which in itself is not necessarily a bad thing), it gives you the link to the question, information about which user posted the multiple answers, and how many answers by that user that was posted.

```
select question.Id as [Post Link], 
   answer.owneruserid as [User Link], 
   count(answer.id) as answers
from Posts question
join Posts answer on (answer.parentid = question.id)
where answer.OwnerUserId != 0
group by answer.OwnerUserId,
  question.id, answer.owneruserid
having count(answer.id) >= 2
order by answers desc
```

The last two `group by` clauses seem quite useless to me in a way, as they will always only be one unique version of them after grouping by `answer.OwnerUserId`. My experience from mySQL is that it simply picks a seemingly random value if not grouping by it, but in the SEDE I get this result:

> Column 'Posts.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

- Is there a way to remove these extra `GROUP BY`'s? Or is adding these "the way it's supposed to be done"?
- How is this SQL overall, regarding performance, naming, structure, conventions and everything?
- Are there any alternative ways to rewrite this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General MySQL/MSSQL comparison**

In regards to the rules for aggregate functions... you have `count(answer.id)` as one of your select values. As a consequence, you need a group by.

The group by must consist of every value that is used as part of any non-aggregate select value, or as part of the order-by.

MySQL's handling for this is 'wrong', and SQLServer is 'right'. I have seen MySQL do this, but, in reality, any system with non-deterministic behaviour is broken, and there is no way to make it deterministic unless you do the group-by right.

**Columns in the Group By**

You only need two columns in the group-by, `question.Id`, and `answers.OwnerUserId`

You have three columns because you have the `answers.OwnerUserId` twice... which is pointless.

**Other suggestions**

- You should, in general, use the same capitalization as the database schema for your tables/columns. Even if the database is case-insensitive.
- You should use all the value predicates you can when running SQL queries. For example, in your code, even though the only place where the conditions `answer.ParentId = questionid and answer.OwnerUserID != 0` happens for questions, and answers, you should also add the predicates `question.PostTypeId = 1 and answer.PostTypeId = 2` (because that is what really makes a question a question, and an answer an answer).

You should bookmark [the SEDE Schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)...

Comment: Rather, MySQL is [broken by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), but can be made sane if you care to configure it with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). _(`SELECT complaint FROM mysql_rants`)_

Comment: Would there be any difference in doing for example `MIN(question.id)` instead of doing an additional GROUP BY for that column?

Comment: huge difference... That would return all users who have answered more than 1 answer on any questions, and the ID of the first question the user answered

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to perform any join at all.

```
SELECT ParentId AS [Post Link]
     , OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
     , COUNT(Id) AS Answers
    FROM Posts
    WHERE
        ParentId IS NOT NULL           -- ← Answers only
        AND OwnerUserId <> 0
    GROUP BY ParentId, OwnerUserId
    HAVING Count(id) > 1
    ORDER BY Answers DESC;
```

Your instinct probably tells you that you need a `JOIN` to obtain the question titles. However, in Stack Exchange Data Explorer, there is a special feature: provide a `PostId` in a column named `[Post Link]`, and it will take care of the presentation for you (implicitly doing a `JOIN`).